# postgres: Locking row data using python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have a postgres( PostgreSQL 12.3) db table which consists of 100k rows and I have a python script which reads from this table and perform some action based on the data. I want to run the same script through multiple machines so that data can be processed faster. But when I run from multiple machines, I want to make sure one row is processed by only one machine at a time, basically achieving it by locking that row.

Can you provide some pointers on how locking row can be achieved through python. I am using psycopg2 module to read and update data from table, but did not find a way to lock the row data.

Answer (score 6):

Use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`, which performs a row-level lock on any rows that are returned, and skips rows that are already locked by another transaction.

Session 1:

```
testdb=# create table tt(x text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# insert into tt select 'foo';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into tt select 'bar';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
testdb=# SELECT * FROM tt ORDER BY x LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
  x  
-----
 bar
(1 row)

testdb=# -- SELECT in session 2 is performed now.
testdb=# commit;
COMMIT
```

Session 2:

```
testdb=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
testdb=# SELECT * FROM tt ORDER BY x LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
  x  
-----
 foo
(1 row)

testdb=# commit;
COMMIT
```

You won't need to do anything special with psycopg2 for this, as long as your query already has a reasonably small limit (so the SELECT doesn't lock every row), adding FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED should do what you're asking for. See [the docs on the locking clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) for more details.

Comment: Session 1:
postgres=# select * from company limit 1 for update skip locked;
 id | name | age |                      address                       | salary
----+------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+--------
  1 | Paul |  32 | California                                         |  20000


Session 2:
postgres=# select * from company limit 1 for update skip locked;
  1 | Paul |  32 | California                                         |  20000

I tried the same , but got same o/p in both sessions. I am using psql shell from default pg install.

Comment: In psql, unless you issue a `BEGIN`, every statement is it's own transaction, so the lock is released as soon as the SELECT finishes. With psycopg2, the transaction is started implicitly and lasts until you issue a `connection.commit()`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Just curious, will there be any chance that two sessions could pick up the same row, and one gets the lock finally? I am just thinking if in that case which session will process the data and wot happens to the other session. In my setup, I am using the same user to access the table in both sessions..

Comment: Also, for pscopyg2, can we say that the transaction will close if the script exits  even if the connect.commit() was not issued, and hence lock is released?

Comment: No, if a connection with an open transaction gets a row from a SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED query, no other transaction can return that from from their own SELECT FOR UPDATE until the 1st has either committed or rolled back. And yes, a connection closing without issuing a commit is treated as a rollback, and the lock will be released as soon as PG notices the connection is closed.